# How to change the color lightness and saturation using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors

I am trying to create a custom color menu from which user can select colors and create of its own by adjusting the *lightness* and *saturation* of the color. My aim is to create something similar to [CUSTOM COLOR](http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/) *(only color adjusting portion using 2 sliders lightness and saturation)*.

*Description about what I tried yet*: I created 2 jqueryui sliders, one for lightness and one for saturation.

```
$("#lightness").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 0,
    min: -0.5,
    max: 0.5,
    step: 0.1,
    slide: function (e, ui) {
     $("#existingcolor").children("div").not("#lightdarkslider,#saturations")
      .each(function (i, v) {
          var color = $(v).attr("title");
          var lightcolor = Lighten(color, ui.value);
          $(v).attr("title", lightcolor).css("backgroundColor", lightcolor);
      });
    }
});

$("#saturation_slider").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 0,
    min: -0.5,
    max: 0.5,
    step: 0.1,
    slide: function (e, ui) {
     $("#existingcolor").children("div").not("#lightdarkslider,#saturations")
       .each(function (i, v) {
        var color = $(v).attr("title");
        var rgb = HEXtoRGB(color);
        var hsv = rgbToHsv(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);
        hsv[1] += ui.value * 32;
        rgb = hsvToRgb(hsv[0], hsv[1], hsv[2]);
        color = RGBtoHEX("rgb(" + rgb[0] + "," + rgb[1] + "," + rgb[2] + ")");
        $(v).attr("title", color).css("backgroundColor", color);
        });
    }
});
```

Now if user slides lightness slider, the function *LIGHTEN* is called. It accepts 3 arguments col(color), by and shade. I am passing color *(value: one by one all existing colors in the pallete)* and by *(value: jQuery ui slider current value)* and shade *(value: it will be always undefined)*.

```
function Lighten(col, by, shade) {
    if (undefined === by) {
        by = 1;
    } else if (by < 0) {
        Darken(col, -by, shade);
    }
    if (undefined === shade) {
        shade = 32;
    }

    var c = HEXtoRGB(col);

    if ((c[0] += shade * by) > 0xff) c[0] = 0xff;
    if ((c[1] += shade * by) > 0xff) c[1] = 0xff;
    if ((c[2] += shade * by) > 0xff) c[2] = 0xff;

    return RGBtoHEX("rgb(" + c[0] + "," + c[1] + "," + c[2] + ")");
}
```

And if user slides saturation slider, than first we get the HSV value of all the existing color in the palette *one by one* and than add the *current slider value* * *32* to saturation value.

This is working up to some extent, but if user slides the slider continuously than all colors become lighten. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong and if there is any other better or easy way to do the same than please let me know?

*Other supporting function*:

```
function Darken(col, by, shade) {
    if (undefined === by) {
        by = 1;
    } else if (by < 0) {
        return Lighten(col, -by, shade);
    }
    if (undefined === shade) {
        shade = 32;
    }

    var c = HEXtoRGB(col);

    if ((c[0] -= shade * by) < 0) c[0] = 0;
    if ((c[1] -= shade * by) < 0) c[1] = 0;
    if ((c[2] -= shade * by) < 0) c[2] = 0;

    return RGBtoHEX("rgb(" + c[0] + "," + c[1] + "," + c[2] + ")");
}

function HEXtoRGB(color) {
    document.getElementById("temp1").style.backgroundColor = color;
    color = document.getElementById("temp1").style.backgroundColor;

    var rgb = color.split(",");
    rgb[0] = parseInt(rgb[0].substring(rgb[0].indexOf("(") + 1));
    rgb[1] = parseInt(rgb[1]);
    rgb[2] = parseInt(rgb[2].substring(0, rgb[2].lastIndexOf(")")));

    return rgb;
}

function hsvToRgb(h, s, v) {

    var s = s / 100,
         v = v / 100;

    var hi = Math.floor((h / 60) % 6);
    var f = (h / 60) - hi;
    var p = v * (1 - s);
    var q = v * (1 - f * s);
    var t = v * (1 - (1 - f) * s);

    var rgb = [];

    switch (hi) {
        case 0: rgb = [v, t, p]; break;
        case 1: rgb = [q, v, p]; break;
        case 2: rgb = [p, v, t]; break;
        case 3: rgb = [p, q, v]; break;
        case 4: rgb = [t, p, v]; break;
        case 5: rgb = [v, p, q]; break;
    }

    var r = Math.min(255, Math.round(rgb[0] * 256)),
        g = Math.min(255, Math.round(rgb[1] * 256)),
        b = Math.min(255, Math.round(rgb[2] * 256));

    return [r, g, b];

}

function rgbToHsv(r, g, b) {
     var r = (r / 255),
         g = (g / 255),
     b = (b / 255);

    var min = Math.min(Math.min(r, g), b),
        max = Math.max(Math.max(r, g), b),
        delta = max - min;

    var value = max,
        saturation,
        hue;

    // Hue  
    if (max == min) {
        hue = 0;
    } else if (max == r) {
        hue = (60 * ((g - b) / (max - min))) % 360;
    } else if (max == g) {
        hue = 60 * ((b - r) / (max - min)) + 120;
    } else if (max == b) {
        hue = 60 * ((r - g) / (max - min)) + 240;
    }

    if (hue < 0) {
        hue += 360;
    }

    // Saturation  
    if (max == 0) {
        saturation = 0;
    } else {
        saturation = 1 - (min / max);
    }

    return [Math.round(hue), Math.round(saturation * 100), Math.round(value * 100)];
}

function RGBtoHEX(rgbstring) {
    var str, rgb, hexstring;
    str = rgbstring.substring(rgbstring.indexOf("(") + 1, rgbstring.indexOf(")"));
    rgb = str.split(",");
    if (rgb.length == 4)
        hexstring = rgbToHex(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2], rgb[3]);
    else if (rgb.length == 3)
        hexstring = rgbToHex(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);
    return hexstring;
}

function rgbToHex(R, G, B, A) {
    if (typeof A == "undefined")
        return "#" + toHex(R) + toHex(G) + toHex(B);
    else
        return "#" + toHex(R) + toHex(G) + toHex(B) + toHex(A);
}

function toHex(n) {
    n = parseInt(n, 10);
    if (isNaN(n)) return "00";
    n = Math.max(0, Math.min(n, 255));
    return "0123456789ABCDEF".charAt((n - n % 16) / 16)
      + "0123456789ABCDEF".charAt(n % 16);
}
```

**EDIT**

*HTML*

```
        <div id="newcolorpicker" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
            <div id="existingcolor" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                <span class="ui-widget-content ui-widget">Drag a color onto an element below </span>
                <br />
                <div class="rc ec col" title="#FFFFFF" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                </div>
                <div class="rc ec col" title="#F2F2F2" style="background-color: #F2F2F2;">
                </div>
                <div class="rc ec col" title="#E6E6E6" style="background-color: #E6E6E6;">
                </div>
                <div class="rc ec col" title="#CCCCCC" style="background-color: #CCCCCC;">
                </div>
                <div class="rc ec col" title="#808080" style="background-color: #808080;">
                </div>
                <div class="rc ec col" title="#4D4D4D" style="background-color: #4D4D4D;">
                </div>
                <div class="rc ec col" title="#000000" style="background-color: #000000;">
                </div>
                <div class="rc ec col" title="#C1272D" style="background-color: #C1272D;">
                </div>
                <div class="rc ec col" title="#ED1C24" style="background-color: #ED1C24;">
                </div>
                <div class="rc ec col" title="#F7931E" style="background-color: #F7931E;">
                </div>
                <div class="rc ec col" title="#FFCC33" style="background-color: #FFCC33;">
                </div>
                <div class="rc ec col" title="#FCEE21" style="background-color: #FCEE21;">
                </div>
                <div class="rc ec col" title="#D9E021" style="background-color: #D9E021;">
                </div>
                <div class="rc ec col" title="#8CC63F" style="background-color: #8CC63F;">
                </div>
                <div class="rc ec col" title="#009245" style="background-color: #009245;">
                </div>
                <div class="rc ec col" title="#006837" style="background-color: #006837;">
                </div>
                <div class="rc ec col" title="#00A99D" style="background-color: #00A99D;">
                </div>
                <div class="rc ec col" title="#33CCCC" style="background-color: #33CCCC;">
                </div>
                <div class="rc ec col" title="#33CCFF" style="background-color: #33CCFF;">
                </div>
                <div class="rc ec col" title="#29ABE2" style="background-color: #29ABE2;">
                </div>
                <div class="rc ec col" title="#0071BC" style="background-color: #0071BC;">
                </div>
                <div class="rc ec col" title="#2E3192" style="background-color: #2E3192;">
                </div>
                <div class="rc ec col" title="#662D91" style="background-color: #662D91;">
                </div>
                <div class="rc ec col" title="#93278F" style="background-color: #93278F;">
                </div>
                <div class="rc ec col" title="#D4145A" style="background-color: #D4145A;">
                </div>
                <div class="rc ec col" title="#ED1E79" style="background-color: #ED1E79;">
                </div>
                <div class="rc ec col" title="#C7B299" style="background-color: #C7B299;">
                </div>
                <div class="rc ec col" title="#736357" style="background-color: #736357;">
                </div>
                <div class="rc ec col" title="#C69C6D" style="background-color: #C69C6D;">
                </div>
                <div class="rc ec col" title="#8C6239" style="background-color: #8C6239;">
                </div>
                <div class="rc ec col" title="#603813" style="background-color: #603813;">
                </div>
                <br />
                <div id="lightdarkslider" class="ui-widget">
                    <div class="lightcontol">
                        <label for="lightness" class="csl">
                            Lightness
                        </label>
                        <div id="lightness" class="cssb uislider">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="saturations" class="ui-widget" style="margin-left: 200px; width: 300px;
                    height: 20px">
                    <div class="saturationcontol">
                        <label for="saturation_slider" class="csl" style="padding-left: 35px;">
                            Saturation
                        </label>
                        <div id="saturation_slider" class="cssb uislider" style="margin: 8px 0 0 15px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Just a quick shot, but shouldn't it be `return Darken(col, -by, shade);` in `Lighten` function?

Comment: Show your HTML code, if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to read the part where they talk about hsla in this post:
http://www.jquerysdk.com/api/jQuery.Color

I hope it helps.